# RestHeart Aggregation: How to sort results?

Tags: restheart

I have an aggregation pipeline in RESTHeart. How can the results be sorted?

In a normal RESTHeart query, we can use the ?sort_by query parameter. However, when adding this to the URL in an aggregation query, the sort does not seem to be honoured.

Another option is to add the sort field in the metadata for the aggregation query - for example like this:

```
            {
                "_$sort" : {
                    "submittedAt" : -1
                }
            },
```

... That works fine for statically-specified fields like the above. But I want to have the sortField changeable (like an avar) and specified in a query variable. I haven't found a way to use avars in this situation. It is possible to specify the sort direction using avars:

```
                "_$sort" : {
                    "submittedAt" : {
                        "_$var" : "dir"
                    }
                }
```

... but how can the key be dynamically specified in the REST request?

Tom

Answer (score 0):

You pass the variable via *avars* query parameter

```
 GET /db/coll/_aggrs/test_ap?avars={"dir":1}
```

For more information refer to the documentation [aggregation section](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/x/AwDw)

The *avars* can be any json, the only limitation is that you cannot pass operators to avoid query injection. So if you want to pass the sort key you can:

Aggregation

```
{ "$sort" : { "$var": "sortExpr" } } }
```

Query

```
 GET /db/coll/_aggrs/test_ap?avars={"sortExpr":{"submittedAt": 1}}
```

**Note** that since restheart 3.0, the _ prefix for operators in not needed anymore.

Comment: Hi Andrea. Thanks for the response. Your code shows how to pass avars, which works fine. I understand how to pass avars, but the question is how to pass the *key* dynamically, as opposed to the value.

In other words, it is the value of the *field name* that needs to change. In my example, it's *submittedAt* that I want to replace with a variable, dynamically.

I think avars only work for values and not keys, currently.

Comment: Hi Tom, I edited the answser to better cover your question